# Bad score in IELTS, should I send it anyway?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, cv, language-exams

A graduate program I'm applying for in mathematics requires fluency in English but didn't set the lower bound for the IELTS score. I'm very good at English but I went to the test unprepared and got severe headache during the test, couldn't complete some tasks so I got 6.

5.5: reading, listening and writing.
7: speaking

But in reality I can do better. My BSc. thesis is well-written so my question is, if I sent my IELTS score would it be a sign of weakness in my application?

It would be very difficult to take another test before the deadline of the application process but not impossible though.

Comment: Nobody here knows what this program's specific admissions criteria are. Could be a simple cutoff, could be that differences in the test are taken into account.

Comment: At my university, there is a minimum IETLS score.  If you don't meet this score, in some special circumstances, we can waive this requirement.  Also, we conduct interviews to judge a candidate; i.e., admission is not based only on one specific criterion.

Comment: Does the application require the test, or just fluency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I went to the test unprepared

One of the purposes of these tests is to see check if you are the sort of person who prepares ahead of time for an examination.  People who have prepared for IELTS get better scores than native speakers who have not prepared.

> if I sent my IELTS score would it be a sign of weakness in my application?

Yes.

> should I send it anyway?

You are close to the typical cutoff score, so we cannot answer this.  You can ask the program.

Comment: _People who have prepared for IELTS get better scores than native speakers who have not prepared._ -- citation needed

Comment: @cag51 Any native speaker who has taken the test, such as myself, will know this.  Of course it is necessary to prepare correctly.